Is there any way to prevent from falling down application if there is no rabbit queues or even rabbit server is not working?
My question is related to rabbitTemplate, how to make an application as fault tolerance, so if even rabbit server is not working it would be launched successfully?
Case:
There is project that has microservice architecture. I have application A, B, C. There is also module that is created as a library named LibA that has rabbit configurations. LibA is imported to application A. If someone will delete queues from rabbit or if rabbit server would not work the application A will fall down. I need to make sure that the problems reltaed to rabbitTemplate must not affect to health of application A.
PS: I dont have enough time to divide application A and LibA, I need fast solution that will not affect to application A. I will make LibA as individual service further, but not now.

This is not a place to post your homework assignments to be done for you.

@BrianC it's not about doing my homework, I'm asking for advice, but thank you for your response

There is class RabbitAdmin which can be configured to create queue if there is not exists.
It would not affect to health of application if rabbit server is not answering or fallen down.
